# InfluxDB query from bash CLI

Tags: bash, syntax, command-line-interface, influxdb

I tested a lot of syntaxes of below query to InfluxDB from bash CLI. But still an error is reported. Seams to be problem with dash (hyphen) in maciej-test statement. Is any workaround or proper syntax to pass such name to CLI InfluxDB? It is strange because everything works file from InfluxDB prompt.

The query:

```
influx -precision rfc3339 -format csv -database test -execute “select mean(“Hum”) as “Hum” from “autogen”.“maciej-test” GROUP BY time(1s) FILL(none) limit 6 tz(‘Europe/Warsaw’)”
```

And the error raport:

```
ERR: error parsing query: found -, expected ; at line 1, char 44
error parsing query: found -, expected ; at line 1, char 44
```

Any idea what I im doing wrong?

EDIT 1

If I use stdin as input for SELECT command, everything works fine, like below:

```
influx -database test -format csv -precision rfc3339 << 'EOF'
select mean("Hum") as "Hum" from "autogen"."maciej-test" GROUP BY time(1s) FILL(none) limit 6 tz('Europe/Warsaw')
EOF
```

Very strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with nested quotes. Either use single quotes around `select`

```
influx -precision rfc3339 -format csv -database test -execute 'select mean(“Hum”) as “Hum” from “autogen”.“maciej-test” GROUP BY time(1s) FILL(none) limit 6 tz("Europe/Warsaw")'
```

or escape nested quotes in `select`:

```
influx -precision rfc3339 -format csv -database test -execute “select mean(\“Hum\”) as \“Hum\” from \“autogen\”.\“maciej-test\” GROUP BY time(1s) FILL(none) limit 6 tz(‘Europe/Warsaw’)”
```

Comment: The first option gives me `ERR: error parsing query: expected string argument in tz()
error parsing query: expected string argument in tz()`

Comment: The second option seems to works OK. I will test it. Both from bash CLI and via curl over network. THX!